# how can i stop the ToolStripMenuItem dropdown menu from removing itself upon selecting an item?

Tags: c#, winforms

A `ToolStripMenuItem` in my `menuStrip` contains all the columns of my table in it's `DropDown` that i can select to hide/unhide but i have to re-open the dropdown (click the item) every time i want to do this. Is there a setting that allows the this menu to persist after an item is selected from it?

I plan on the Dropdown to only close when the mouse hovers off of it ideally, or when another control in my window is selected (which i would assume is the `Lose Focus` event).

I implemented the first answer to this but it has a really noticeable flicker every time an item is selected: 
[image]

The first way i tried to fix it involved disabling `item.DropDown.AutoClose` but that introduces the question of what events trigger `AutoClose` so i can re-implement the events that i want. i tried `MouseLeave` and `LoseFocus` events but i can't seem to get them to work for this purpose in a reliable way. (read my responses to the first answer)

Comment: Do you mean you added a ToolStripButton to the MenuStrip? Or is it a ToolStrip? If it's a ToolStripButton inside a MenuStrip, what kind of Menu is it opening? Do you plan on closing the DropDown when the Button is clicked a second time? Have you tested the AutoClose property? An Image of your current layout could help. Posting the code you've written so far to handle this can also help.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a method that will reopen the menu strip item programmatically and call it from the button click event.
 here is an example for such method:

```
private void OpenDropDown(int dropindex = 0)
{
    ToolStripDropDownItem item = menuStrip1.Items[dropindex] as ToolStripDropDownItem;

    if (item.HasDropDownItems)
    {
        // Re-openes the menustrip item
        item.ShowDropDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but the menu flickers whenever an item is selected. The way i tried to fix it involved disabling `item.DropDown.AutoClose`  but that introduces the issue of what events trigger `AutoClose` so i can re-implement the events that i want. I tried the closing on the `MouseLeave` event but  that requires the mouse to enter the dropdown control first. i'd need to somehow have the event apply to both the `item` and it's `dropdown` and not trigger unless the mouse leaves both of them and not just one, but idk how.

Comment: In trying to find the equivalent events that trigger `AutoClose`:

The `LostFocus` event never seems to trigger unless it's the `item` that is regaining the focus. the `item` also seems to regain focus immediately upon unclicking after i give the `DropDown` focus in the click event, so there's that issue too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the OnDropDownClosing event. Add this handler to all the items you wish to click but the menu should remain open.

```
private static void OnDropDownClosing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.ItemClicked)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Maybe for `ToolStripDropDown` but this event does not exist for `ToolStripMenuItem`.